# How to open multiple nodejs command prompts in windows?

Tags: node.js, command-prompt

For a class, I am using a node js command prompt. In windows only when i search node js command prompt am I able to open the command prompt. This command prompt is basically the regular windows command prompt with edhanced features of node. For example I use the node js command prompt to do things like npm install, npm run serve, etc. I know that to open another window of regular windows command prompt, i can run start cmd.exe  but how so can I do with my node js command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine if I run "Node Command Prompt" a 2nd time, it opens a 2nd window.

---

If you want to do the same thing, the shortcut that Node installs just runs:

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"

so you should be able to run that, assuming your node install location is Program Files\nodejs.

Comment: I want to able to open two of these windows if that makes sense? i can open a normal node js comand prompt ( not the repl) by searching for it, but i need to be able to have more then 1 opened at once

Answer (score 0):

Open your environment variables config, and add these 2 directories to `Path` variable.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

And then every time you open a regular cmd window, the node.js commands will be available to you.